# Override a Core Magento Payment Method

Tags: php, magento-1.9, payment-processing

I'm trying to override the Purchase Order payment method in Magento v1.9.2.

All I'm trying to add is

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
```

Based on this **[Article](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-change-invoice-status-in-admin.html)**

I've quickly tested it by changing the **`core Purchaseorder.php file`** and it works fine (invoicing give me options to capture offline or not capture), now I'm trying to override it to upgrade-proof my site.

I know I need to upload 3 files:

I've put the **`config.xml`** below in

> **/httpdocs/app/code/local/Autoeurope/Payment/etc**

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Autoeurope_Payment>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Autoeurope_Payment>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <payment>
              <rewrite>
                  <class>Autoeurope_Payment_Model_Method</class>
              </rewrite>
          </payment>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I've put the below **`Autoeurope_Payment.xml`** in

> **/httpdocs/app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>  
    <modules>  
        <Autoeurope_Payment>  
            <active>true</active>  
            <codePool>local</codePool>  
        </Autoeurope_Payment>  
    </modules>  
</config>
```

and I've put the below **`Purchaseorder.php`** in

> **/httpdocs/app/code/local/Autoeurope/Payment/Model/Method**

```
class Autoeurope_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder
{
    protected $_code  = 'purchaseorder';
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_formBlockType = 'payment/form_purchaseorder';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info_purchaseorder';

    /**
     * Assign data to info model instance
     *
     * @param   mixed $data
     * @return  Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder
     */
    public function assignData($data)
    {
        if (!($data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            $data = new Varien_Object($data);
        }

        $this->getInfoInstance()->setPoNumber($data->getPoNumber());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I've got the cache disabled, logged out and logged in etc and created new orders each time I've tried something but to no avail, I'm sure it's something small but I just can't see the problem I'm afraid.

Comment: check your logs. and past here if there is any error report..

Comment: I've just checked, there isn't any reported